# Scalable patterns for thread-safe hashtable puts when keeping track of frequency

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, design-patterns, hashtable

This was an interview question I got some time last week and it ended at a cliffhanger. The question was simple: Design a service that keeps track of the frequency of "messages" (a 1 line string, could be in different languages) passed to it. There are 2 broad apis: submitMsg(String msg) and getFrequency(String msg). My immediate reaction was to use as hashMap that uses a String as a key (in this case, a message) and an Integer as a value (to keep track of counts/frequency).

The submitMsg api simply sees whether a message exists in the hashMap. If it doesn't, put the message and set the frequency to 1; if it does, then get the current count and increment it by 1. The interviewer then pointed out this would fail miserably in the event multiple threads access the SAME key at the SAME exact time.

For example: At 12:00:00:000 Thread1 would try to "submitMsg", and thereby my method would do a (1) get on the hashMap and see that the value is not null, it is infact, say 100 (2) do a put by incrementing the frequency by 1 so that the key's value is 101. Meanwhile consider that Thread2 ALSO tried to do a submitMsg at exactly At 12:00:00:000, and the method once again internally did a get on the hashMap (which returned a 100 - this is a race condition), after which the hashMap now increments the frequency to 101. Alas, the true frequency should have been 102 and not 101, and this is a major design flaw in a largely multithreaded environment. I wasn't sure how to stop this from happening: Putting a lock on simply the write isn't good enough, and having a lock on a read didn't make sense. What would have been ideal is to "lock" an element if a get was invoked internally via the submitMsg api because we expect it to be "written to" soonafter. The lock would be released once the frequency had been updated, but if someone were to use the getFrequency() api having a pure lock wouldn't make sense. I'm not sure whether a mutex would help here because I don't have a strong background in distributed systems.

I'm looking to the SO community for help on the best way to think through a problem like this. Is the magic in the datastructure to be used or some kind of synchronization that I need to do in my api itself? How can we maintain the integrity of "frequency" while maintaining the scalability of the service as well?

Comment: This is really more of a theoretical CS question, so probably off-topic for SO. Also, Java's `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably appropriate here.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: I see here no theoretical CS, unless you consider the whole `java.util.concurrent` to be a theoretical exercise.

Comment: Enclosing the *whole* increment operation in lock would. You'd need use the lock when reading too, in order to ensure visibility (otherwise the reading thread could continue to use its cached value). However, a solution like in the Aurand's answer is way more efficient and scales better with the number of threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your initial idea isn't a million miles off, you just need to make it thread safe.  For instance, you could use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>`.

```
public void submitMsg(String msg) {
    AtomicInteger previous = map.putIfAbsent(msg, new AtomicInteger(1));
    if (null != previous) {
        previous.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my first run-in with java's atomicInteger, much obliged! In the event we did _not_ have access to such a wrapper class (I understand that the tags include "java", but just to make my understanding concrete) or a very specific library like maaartinus outlined, what would your recommendation be? Is there anything more scalable than locking the "get + put"?

Comment: @BSJ Well, practically speaking, no matter what your language you will probably either have similar concurrency abstractions, or the tools necessary to build them.  The producer-consumer answer gives an interesting alternative approach (effectively making interactions with your map single threaded), though there are some performance problems there.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is using Guava's com.google.common.collect.ConcurrentHashMultiset:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMultiset<String> multiset = ConcurrentHashMultiset.create();

public void submitMsg(String msg) {
    multiset.add(msg);
}

public int count(String msg) {
    return multiset.count(msg);
}
```

But this is basically the same as Aurand's solution, just that somebody already implemented the boring details like creating the counter if it doesn't exists yet, etc.

Comment: I had a vague memory that there was probably a Guava solution for this problem.  +1 for common utils.

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as a [Producer–consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

The service is the producer; it should add each message to a queue that feeds the consumer. You could run one queue per producer to ensure that the producers do not wait.

The consumer encapsulates the HashTable, and pulls the messages off the queue and updates the table.